# How old is the chanukiyah?

Tags: history, menora-chanukia

Another question asks about the differentiation between the words "chanukiyah" and "menorah" when referring to the special 8-branched (+1) candelabra for Chanukah.  An [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4498/472) there suggests:

> All of the rest of their references to the Chanukah lights indeed use the term נר(ות) חנוכה. I'd guess that indeed the average person in those days didn't have a specially-designed candelabra for this purpose (or if they did, it wasn't branched like the original menorah)...

This seems plausible; I can't recall seeing older writings that refer to a special device, just references to lights.  So my question is:  How old is the *chanukiyah*, meaning a special candelabra that we use only for Chanukah and that has the correct number of wicks/candles?  I'm interested in any evidence, whether from halachic literature, art, or known artifacts.

Comment: possibly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22603/759

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Neiros Shabbos - No 95](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28663&st=&pgnum=8) shows a picture of a Chanuka Menora from the 15th century in Sicily.

[Jewish Art Museum of Minessota](http://jewishartmuseummn.blogspot.com/2009/11/hanukiot-12-13th-century.html) has 2 pictures of Menoras from the 13th century. One from Avignon and the other from Germany /Northern France.

According to this [press release](http://www.prlog.org/10161254-brooklyn-museum-hosts-worlds-oldest-recorded-hanukkah-menorah.html) - [The Living Torah Museum](http://www.torahmuseum.com/) has the oldest known Chanuka Menora on display. I spoke to Rabbi Shaul Shimon Deutsch the owner of the museum. He said they did a test on this Chanuka Menora and they carbon dated and certified it from 60 years after the miracle of Chanuka in the 1st century!

> During a recent archaeological excavation in Jerusalem, one of the
>   workers uncovered an unusual artifact that was brought to the
>   attention of the office of Antiquities. Crafted from hand pottery and
>   small enough to be held in the palm of an adults hand, this ancient
>   discovery has been determined to be what is known to be the world’s
>   oldest recorded Hanukkah Menorah known to mankind since the
>   establishment of the Hanukkah holiday. Accompanied by a certified
>   letter of authenticity, issued by the Head of Antiquities, this
>   Menorah has found it’s way through a private donor to a museum based
>   in the Orthodox Jewish community of Boro Park, located in Brooklyn New
>   York.

Comment: Very cool, thanks!  I had no idea they were that old.  (Also, wall-hung chanukiyot, like the second one from the Jewish Art Museum of Minnesota, are a new idea to me -- I'm so used to "put it in your window" that hanging them from a wall had never occurred to me.)

Comment: Y"K for the legwork, and great find! Any chance you could get him to provide pictures and more detailed info? Publicization of this artifact is a great advertisement for his museum.

Comment: [This Yated article](http://strangeside.com/chanuka-unusual-menorahs/) has more on the Living Torah Museum's artifact.

Comment: Any news on including pictures in this answer?

Comment: Unfortunately the second link has died (and the Wayback Machine doesn't have it).