# Is there any basis for reserving the term "menorah" to the one in the Beis Hamikdash?

Tags: words, chanuka, menora-chanukia

I was taught in kindergarten that "menorah" refers specifically to the menorah in the Beis Hamikdash, and the proper term for the thing used to hold Chanuka candles is "Chanukiyah".

But in all the sources, menorah just means a lamp (randomly chosen [example](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.5.2)), and the [Chayei Adam](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.154.11) that calls the one used for Chanuka מנורת חנוכה, as do several others on Bar Ilan.

Is there any basis for avoiding the term "menorah" when referring to the Chanuka menorah, or for that matter an electric lamp?

Comment: Kings 2:4:10 נעשה-נא עליית-קיר קטנה, ונשים לו שם מיטה ושולחן וכיסא ומנורה; והיה בבואו אלינו, יסור שמה.clearly there's much basis for not having such reservations.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4493/759